# using Facebook oAuth in my site

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I started integrating social network in my site .But i am facing some problem.

1. I can't figure out the best way to login in Facebook and Google .I read that using `FB.logout()` is not a best practice and everyone should use a varible that will just vanish the fb login button after login using fb. But what will be the scenario? when the user login my site using facebok and then he just log out from my site . I heard some thing about `access_token` what is the use of that . Does it track the user login?
2. I have used Facebook JS SDK to login. When I login to my site using facebook i need to refresh  by pressing F5 or refresh icon to get the value from session . using `location.reload()` or `window.location.reload()` is not sufficient to get the value from the session.
   and i am testing it in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to refresh to use FB Login. JS and PHP SDK. This is why I am after 3 years considering to stop using it. Well it also frustrates, that it bugs a lot. For example you will be logged out after clicking a link or it just returns errors instead of catching your token to log you in.

So I highly advice some sort of normal login script via session and maybe use social media login as a second way for users to login.

You may check http://Lightningsoul.com for my FB login script and in case you find it better than I do, still do whatever you want to. ;)